# Regular expression for sentences or questions

Tags: android, regex, pattern-matching

```
        String regex ="((?:get|what is) number)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);       
        String text ="what is the number";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        boolean flag= matcher.matches();
        Log.i("===matches or not??","==="+flag);
```

So the text may be "get the number","get number","what is the number","what's the number","tell me the number","give me number"

My code works fine for "get number" and "what is number"
where "the" is optional. and I'm not able to add  "the as optional field in the above regex"

So if I give input "what is the number" then it will return false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add an optional group with the word, `(?:\s+the)?`:

```
String regex ="((?:tell me|g(?:et|ive me)|what(?:\\s+i|')s)(?:\\s+the)?\\s+number)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);       
String text ="what is the number";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
boolean flag= matcher.matches();
```

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/OMpDsV).

The pattern will look like

```
((?:tell me|g(?:et|ive me)|what(?:\s+i|')s)(?:\s+the)?\s+number)
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note I replaced spaces with `\s+` to match any 1+ whitespace chars and compiled the regex with the `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag to enable case insensitive matching. I also added the alternatives to match more variations of the input string.

See the [regex online demo](https://regex101.com/r/uhYjjU/2).

Comment: It works .Thank you so much @Wiktor Stribiżew for your quick and simpler solution